Lo que, por el contrario, la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o Viena
En esta entrada de la wikipedia, encontramos el siguiente párrafo:

La capitalidad de Madrid, con sus evidentes efectos espaciales,
funcionales y fisonómicos, constituye el hecho diferencial de Madrid
en relación con el resto de ciudades españolas, lo que, por el
contrario, la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o
Viena.

No entiendo esta parte:

lo que, por el contrario, la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o Viena.

"Por el contrario" significa "al revés o de manera opuesta". ¿Es está diciendo que si la primera parte del párrafo no fuera cierto sobre Madrid, entonces la segunda parte del párrafo sería verdadera (que no entiendo su significado)? Me siento confundidísimo, por favor, ayúdenme. ¡Muchas gracias!

Deberías ajustar el título de la pregunta a algo más global, SSE es un web para todos, no solo para un usuario. "Lo que, por el contrario, la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o Viena" no significa absolutamente nada para quien esté intentando solucionar una duda.

How do I write a good title

¡Muchísimas gracias a todos!

‘Madrid's capital status, with its evident spatial, functional and physiognomic effects, constitutes the differential fact of Madrid in relation to the rest of Spanish cities, which, on the contrary, brings it closer to other European capitals, such as Paris, London or Vienna’.
Here it is articulated that Madrid is more in line with other European cities than with the other Spanish cities. And you are right that 'por el contrario' (on the contrary) is not so well chosen here: 'por lo tanto' (as a result, therefore, consequently, thus) habría sido una opción más coherente.

No tiene sentido decir que el hecho de que la centralidad de una  capital la aleje de otras ciudades connacionales sea la causa de que esa capital se acerque cualitativamente a capitales extranjeras. "Por lo tanto" no es un nexo coherente. Es un absurdo.

@Gustavson No te preocupes en comentar, todas las respuestas de este usuario son copy/paste de inteligencia artificial.

physiognomic? Usually for people. It is articulated that x? Check your grammar.

@Danielillo Gracias por tu información. De todos modos, los comentarios pueden ser aclaratorios para los usuarios en general.

@Lambie It seems this user uses  AI and will not take the trouble to check anything. And OP will take his answer as true.

@Gustavson Yes, so we need to get rid of him. I was looking at the profile, it's only two months old.

Oxford languages: physiognomy (noun) · physiognomies (plural): the general form or appearance of something: "the physiognomy of the landscape"

A mi entender, "por el contrario" es un buen nexo en esa oración. Los extremos que se oponen son, por un lado, "hecho diferencial ... en relación con el resto de ciudades españolas" y, por el otro, "la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o Viena."
O sea, si bien esas características de Madrid la diferencian de otras ciudades españolas, la aproximan a otras capitales europeas.
Ejemplo de "por el contrario" en Fundéu:

La Ley de Dependencia apenas se está aplicando en Madrid; por el contrario, en el resto de España ya favorece a más del setenta por ciento de las personas afectadas.

Hagamos la analogía con el ejemplo en cuestión:

La capitalidad de Madrid la diferencia del resto de ciudades españolas; por el contrario, esa capitalidad la acerca a otras capitales europeas, como París, Londres o Viena.

Ambas oraciones presentan un contraste, para lo cual "por el contrario" es un nexo apropiado.
Consultada la Fundéu, no encuentra problema con el uso de "por el contrario", pero objeta el uso de "lo que" -- supongo que no les resulta claro el antecedente:


Está mal. ‘Por el contrario’ se opone a toda la frase anterior, no a ‘ciudades españolas’. Que Madrid se acerque a otras capitales viene reforzado por el hecho de que se diferencie de las demás ciudades españolas. No hay ninguna oposición de ninguna idea.

La frase que citas contiene dos opuestos, por lo que «por lo contrario» se utiliza correctamente.
La frase que tú haces no contiene ninguna contradicción, por lo tanto no puedes utilizar "por lo contrario".

FundéuRAE no opina lo mismo.
